# How do I copy Command Line Text? System Monitor > Processes > Column "Command Line"

Tags: command-line, startup, startup-applications

Startup Applications Preferences

I'm adding additional startup programs, and I've found it most easy to just launch up the Process tab and type command (manually) from the Command Input Field. I just wish I could CTRL + C the selected field so I could CTRL + V into the Command input field in Startup Applications > Add > Command.

[image: Command Input Field]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `xclip` command. Then you can use the

`ps aux | grep 'your specification' | xclip -selection clipboard`

to copy the command in to the system clipboard.
Here is the `xclip` [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Process Tab, but you could on a console type:

```
ps -C <command name> -ww -o args
```

This will print the full command line to the console and this can be copied.